# PHP multidimensional array update/add new key in already saved key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is previously saved array.

```
$market_data_array = get_option('market_data');

Array
(
    [Turkey] => Array
        (
            [Gold] => Array
                (
                    [2020] => Array
                        (
                            [March] => Array
                                (
                                    [12] => 25000
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

This is how I'm updating the array with new data.

```
$country_name = 'Turkey';
$rates_property_type = 'Silver';
$year = '2020';
$month = 'March';
$day_date = '12';
$rate_today = 8000;

$market_data_array[] = array(
    "".$country_name."" => array(
        "".$rates_property_type."" => array(
            "".$year."" => array(
                "".$month."" => array(
                    "".$day_date."" => "".$rate_today."",
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);

update_option('market_data', $market_data_array);
```

This is how new array should be updated.

```
Array
(
    [Turkey] => Array
        (
            [Gold] => Array
                (
                    [2020] => Array
                        (
                            [March] => Array
                                (
                                    [12] => 25000
                                )

                        )

                )

            [Silver] => Array
                (
                    [2020] => Array
                        (
                            [March] => Array
                                (
                                    [12] => 8000
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I am saving market data for multiple countries with multiple property types in one array & in one WordPress database option.

It seems simple, but my brain is puzzled. It gave me headache from last 5 hours. I will be thankful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way.

```
<?php
$market_data_array =array (
    'Turkey' => 
    array (
        'Gold' => 
        array (
            2020 => 
            array (
                'March' => 
                array (
                    12 => 25000
                ),

            ),

        ),

    ),

);

$country_name = 'Turkey';
$rates_property_type = 'Silver';
$year = '2020';
$month = 'March';
$day_date = '12';
$rate_today = 8000;

$market_data_array[$country_name][$rates_property_type][$year][$month][$day_date] = $rate_today;
print_r($market_data_array);
```

**Sample:** https://3v4l.org/5MkRI

Comment: - please can you explain its working for my understanding or just tell why my method was not working. thanks

Comment: I am finding it hard to explain in words. Here is what you seems to be doing. https://3v4l.org/bXopC

Comment: yes, you are right about my method. Anyhow you solved my problem. lets close here. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_merge_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive) to generate the updated market data:

```
$country_name = 'Turkey';
$rates_property_type = 'Silver';
$year = '2020';
$month = 'March';
$day_date = '12';
$rate_today = 8000;

$new_market_data = array(
    "".$country_name."" => array(
        "".$rates_property_type."" => array(
            "".$year."" => array(
                "".$month."" => array(
                    "".$day_date."" => "".$rate_today."",
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);

$market_data_array = array_merge_recursive($market_data_array, $new_market_data);
print_r($market_data_array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Turkey] => Array
        (
            [Gold] => Array
                (
                    [2020] => Array
                        (
                            [March] => Array
                                (
                                    [12] => 25000
                                )
                        )
                )
            [Silver] => Array
                (
                    [2020] => Array
                        (
                            [March] => Array
                                (
                                    [12] => 8000
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/US5ZV)

Comment: let me test it.

Comment: it is working, but it is adding multiple arrays with year [2021], [2022] each time I update.

Comment: @samar I'm not sure what you mean? It will only add an array with year 2021 if the data contains that. Can you set up a demo that shows the problem?